# SharePoint 2010 Surface Content on Port 80

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

SharePoint newbiew question, I have installed SharePoint 2010 and want to be able to browse something on port 80. When SP configured it's self it only created 'http://spimage:32001/'  32001, so I manually created one on Port 80 (SharePoint - 80  'http://spimage/'  80) from Central Admin but when I browse to this I just get a 404.

I created a site collection thinking it would reside under port 80 to put something on it. (http://spimage/sites/SPFWebApp/Pages/default.aspx), I can browse this site fine.

My ultimate goal is to be able to browse port 80 and show something surfaced on SharePoint (Hello World for want of a better word), does anyone know how I achieve such an easy task :)

I would like to be able to display my Site Collection but it doesn't have to be that.

Cheers

p.s. if I go to IIS and browse SharePoint - 80 I get nothing.

Comment: SO is for programming related questions not power user questions. Try sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Comment: Well I'm a programmer and view this as a development related question, could be wrong...Developers do setup and need to know what they are doing? Take your point on SE...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some things mixed up here when you are trying to have another URL/Port for a site collection which is not possible.

SharePoint is based on Web Applications - one SharePoint WebApp can be multiple IIS Web Applications. When you create a new Web Application via Central Administration > Application Management > New you can specify the port and host header the site should listen to.

[image]

SharePoint also creates the "IIS web site" or IIS web application for you with the name "SharePoint - 80" in this case.
[image]

But when I now try to browse this new page I get this:
[image]

**Why is that?**. Right now my server doesn't know how to handle "mynewsharepoint.local". So either I add a DNS entry for that or I go the easy route and add an entry to the hosts file (C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc):

```
127.0.0.1 mynewsharepoint.local
```

I now get a 404:
[image]

**Why?** There is no site collection in my newly created web application. So i go ahead and create a site collection at http://mynewsharepoint.local/:
[image]

And voilá it works:
[image]

---

Summary:

- Check that you have your custom host header routed in the hosts file
- Make sure you have a site collection within your web application
- Check in IIS that the "default web site" on port 80 is stopped

Comment: We are having an issue where our Port 80 site is redirecting to a /_layouts/error.aspx. We just installed SharedPoint on our servers. What could be causing this.  I tried creating a site collection based on a Teamsite template from Central Adminsitration, but that did not see to take because once I navigated to that new path for the site collection it just tacked on the /_layouts/error.aspx on it.